Suggest to rename tag "tie" to "perl-tie"
Having a Perl question that seems related to the tie operation, I noticed that there's a tag named tie to be used for Perl's tie.
However I think the name of the tie tag is somewhat too generic.
So I'm proposing to rename it to perl-tie.
As https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2189130/kmdreko asked for it:
Perl's tie mechanism allows to override methods of (typically) an  array or a hash variable, and the most common use is to "tie" such a variable to a database backend to make the particular variable persistent in a transparent way. I hope the explanation is good enough.

not only that, but it's been used for things that aren't perl a number of times as well

Yeesh, the tag is a mess. I see at least two other main uses: combining things together (both for a specific function with that name and in a generic sense), and when two things are equal (either in timing, a game, or other metric). I'm not familiar with "tie" in the Perl sense, but it sounds like its ubiquitous enough to warrant a tag, but I'd opt for retagging/renaming those and burninating the rest. Its not that many questions.

@kmdreko Is one of them the vast majority of uses (such that we should go ahead and rename the tag to it, fixing the mistags later), or is there more of a ... tie?

@RyanM I see 86 [tie] questions and 52 are tagged [perl] as well.

If you rename it A C++ tag might need to be added as well since std::tie exists and it looks like there a some question about it in this tag.

The C++ tag for tie already exists https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-tie, so I've gone ahead and retagged the handful of C++ questions appropriately. (Apart from a question about std::cin.tie and a question about boost::tie, the rest were directly replaceable with the appropriate tag.)
